# Unable to set password on a drive item from graph api on OneDrive business user account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, file-permissions, onedrive

I am working with graph api, using which I want to share a drive item via link with password and expiration date set on it. The documentation said to use this api: '''https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/createLink'''. The body for the request is
'''{

```
"type" : "view",
"scope": "anonymous",
"password": "XXXXXXX"
```

}'''.
But when I make a post request, I am getting an error
'''{

```
"error": {
    "code": "-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException",
    "message": "The parameter password does not exist in method createLink.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "XXXXXX",
        "request-id": "XXXXXX",
        "client-request-id": "XXXXXX"
    }
}
```

}'''.

The drive that I am using is a business account user drive(user@company.com). Any help in this regard to resolve the issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) it is specified that you should use password field only on Personal OneDrive.

Comment: Are you still looking for help?

Comment: Moving this to Answer :)-

Answer (score 0):

As it is specified in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createlink?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body) that you should use password field or password property only on the Personal OneDrive.

If you want to use you Work account to create link, you can remove the password field and its value and use the call, it will work.

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/{driveId}/items/{itemId}/createLink
```

Request Body:

```
{
    "type" : "view",
    "scope": "anonymous"
}
```